# Selecting rows from another boolean dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, conditional-statements, selection

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.
df1 contains integers and df2 contains booleans.
df1 and df2 are exactly the same size (like both are 10x10).
I would like to create a df3 that would take the data from df1 only if the value in the same location in df2 is True. All False would be replaced by Nan in df3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: Does `df1.where(df2)` solve your question?

Comment: It gives me a DataFrame full of nan

Comment: Make shure the columns and indexes match or use `df1.where(df2.to_numpy())`. Please add example data to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.